# Configure list form to hide columns based on CurrentUser.email value in Sharepoint Online

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

Followed this link to customize list forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections

I applied conditional formula `=if([$Assignedto.email]==[$CurrentUser.email], 'true', 'false')` to column **Assigned to** but it does not work

My original requirement was to hide the section entirely. Is it possible through modern UI json formatting for List forms?

Edit: I tried `=if([$Assignedto.email]==@me, 'true', 'false')`
It still did not work. Only hides the column completely regardless of condition is true/false

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I could reproduce your issue on my end. The conditional formula looks not work work Person columns. Seems like a bug.

Also I tried with this : `=if([$Assignedto.email]=='michael@company.com', 'true', 'false')`. The column would be awlays hidden.

Comment: I checked with a few MVP guys they're saying its a preview feature hence may not work properly. Don't know why they bring such features over production when they don't even work.